# jQuery dataTables changing the input search

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

The default HTML generated by the plugin dataTables for the `search input` is the following:

```
<div id="projects_table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
    <label> 
            Search: <input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="projects_table">
    </label>
</div>
```

I would like to change the content inside the class `dataTables_filter` and still be able to search.

```
$(function(){
    if($('.dataTable').length > 0){
        $('.dataTable').dataTable({
            "bFilter": true,
        });

        $('.dataTables_filter').empty(); // clears the content generated    
        $('.dataTables_filter').append("<div class='input-group' style='width: 250px'>" + 
                                       "    <input type='search' class='form-control' placeholder='Search..'/>" +
                                       "    <span class='input-group-addon'>" +
                                       "        <i class='fa fa-search' style='width: 15px; padding-left: 5px'></i>" +
                                       "    </span>" +
                                       "</div>")
    }
});
```

After "re-code" the div, the content is:

```
<div id="projects_table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
    <div class="input-group" style="width: 250px">  
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">   
            <span class="input-group-addon">        
                <i class="fa fa-search" style="width: 15px; padding-left: 5px"></i> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it does not work. I'm wondering if I have to activate the functionality again? But if so, how?

**EDIT 1**: I'm currently creating a JSFiddle.

**EDIT 2**: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlefan/1bLyfbw9/

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use the `sDom` property to hide the default search input. Add your own and use `fnFilter()` to perform a search.

Comment: Tried to do something with `fnFilter()` but I get `undefined` in console. `$(document).on('keyup', "input[type='search']", function(){
 $('.dataTable').fnFilter($(this).value);
});`

Comment: Ok, managed to get this working with your tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved**, here's the solution:

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input[type='search']", function(){
    var oTable = $('.dataTable').dataTable();
    oTable.fnFilter($(this).val());
});
```